# The simulation hypothesis and the halting problem

Tags: quantum-information, information, computational-physics

I have a basic knowledge of classical and quantum information which isn't remotely enough to make me an expert on the subject. That being said, reading some questions about the [simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis) made me wonder: since with our current theories we can, in principle, know the ultimate fate of the universe, wouldn't that conflict with the halting problem, which is to my knowledge an universal propriety of Turing machines?

In other words, if our universe is a simulation inside a Turing machine, or a Turing machine itself, it should be impossible to us, even in principle, to know when the computation ends? Since this is an "open problem" in physics/ metaphysics, I was wondering, what is the fallacy in this line of reasoning?

Comment: The idea that physics can tell you the fate of the universe is a complete misrepresentation of speculative extrapolations of cosmological models that are far from fully developed. While it's popular to talk about these things in books for laymen and on tv there is nothing we know for sure about the long term future of the universe and very little that we can reliably defend even based on existing data and a (random) choice of cosmological model. Even if we knew these things they would not impact any of the mathematical results pertaining to computability.

Comment: If the universe goes trough phase transitions like the one that we are inferring happened at $T_{cosmological}=0$ (aka "big bang"), then it's probably pretty safe to assume that the total amount of (usable) information that survives these transitions is very limited. Indeed, one can probably construct fairly simple and self-consistent cosmologies that are an endless series of such events. In information theoretical terms these are like near total resets, so the past is as simple as a "pop" and the future is unknowable.

Comment: very nice insight thank you. You are right i did put my question in a somewhat vague form regarding the part on the possibility to predict the distant future, anyway what i meant (and wanted to know) is exactly what you wrote in the second comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for *all* possible program-input pairs cannot exist.

Therefore, a solution to the halting problem for the particular pair of initial conditions and laws of motion associated to our universe (if such a thing even really exists) actually would not violate Turing's proof.

That said, it's not even clear to me that a universe with prescribed initial conditions and laws of motion even is a Turing machine. The traditional Turing machine executes discrete instructions one at a time. This is somewhat different from the continuous time system we think our universe uses.

Comment: Nice, i think that settles it for me.